# Advanced spring-data query/critera

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have been building a Spring based REST service using MongoDB and Spring Data - MongoDB.

See below; parts of my data model:

```
@Document
public class User{
    .....
    private List<EMail> emails;
    .....
}

public class EMail {
    .....
    private bool defaultMail;
    private String eMailAdress;
    .....
}
```

EMail is not annotated as a MongoDb Document.

I would like to achieve following functions in the Repository.

```
public Boolean exists(String email);
public User getUserByEmail(String email);
```

I can implement simple queries using Query and the Criteria API, but have not been successful achieving above functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer on my own question and I would like to share.

The query should look like this:

```
query (where("emails").elemMatch(where("eMailAdress").is(email)))
```

I found the answer by reading MongoDb manual,,, which turns out is much more understandable than spring-data manual.

//lg